# Python Pandas: How to remove the outliers in a column, and replace them with prior values (assuming they are not outlier)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date | Value. 
2020-03-18 10 
2020-03-19 20 
2020-03-20 30 
2020-03-21 25 
2020-03-22 35 
2020-03-23 50 
2020-03-24 1900000 
2020-03-25 1200000 
2020-03-26 50 
2020-03-27 25 
2020-03-28 35 
2020-03-29 50 
2020-03-30 25 
2020-03-31 35 
... 
2021-01-31 45
```

What is the quickest way for me to replace the outliers in `value` column with prior non-outlier values?

I need to be careful not to simply replace outlier with prior number, because it would mess up if the prior value is also an outlier (as seen in `2020-03-24`).

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What do you consider an `outlier`?

Comment: what do you mean by prior values? whare are they coming from?

Comment: @QuangHoang  values that are more than 3 standard deviation from the mean

Comment: @zafrin prior row whose value is not an outlier, if that makes sense

Comment: There are no `outliers` in your data according to your criteria.

Comment: @QuangHoang those are just some pseudo numbers I put there for illustration purpose

Comment: @user275428 still, you should provide your sample so as there are some. Anyhow, see my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, your sample data do not have outlier. However, according to your logic, you can do:

```
std, mean = df['Value'].agg(['std','mean'])

df['Value'] = df['Value'].where(df['Value'].between(mean-3*std, mean+3*std)).ffill()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.